# Combining 2 SELECT queries

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

So I have 2 queries which I want to use together to product one output result to the user. The output describes to the user the journey to take to from A to B. I keep getting a syntax error when I am trying to join the result of my first query to my second.

```
Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNION" LINE 6: UNION ^
```

I have had a look at a similar question but the solutions & discussions provided do not seem to work.

```
$name = pg_escape_string($_POST['name']); // Start destination from user input
$name2 = pg_escape_string($_POST['name2']); // End destination from user input

//If no results are given, the following query below will execute instead.

if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {

$query = "SELECT dt1.name as name1,dt1.time as time1,dt2.name as    name2,dt2.time as time2
From departure_times as dt1
inner join departure_times as dt2 on dt2.tram_id = dt1.tram_id

UNION 

SELECT dt1.name as name3,dt1.time as time3,dt2.name as name4,dt2.time as    time4
From departure_times as dt1
inner join departure_times as dt2 on dt2.tram_id = dt1.tram_id;

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

} .....


The desired output I am looking for is the following :

      ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        name1 | time1  | name2  | time2 | name3 |  time3    | name4  | time4
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Add brackets around each subquery: `(select ... limit 5) union (select ... limit 5)`

Comment: Like so : @Abelisto

$query = ("SELECT dt1.name as name1,dt1.time as time1,dt2.name as name2,dt2.time as time2
From departure_times as dt1
inner join departure_times as dt2 on dt2.tram_id = dt1.tram_id
where dt1.name = '$name' and dt2.name = 'CitySquare' ) 

UNION 

(SELECT dt1.name as name3,dt1.time as time3,dt2.name as name4,dt2.time as time4
From departure_times as dt1
inner join departure_times as dt2 on dt2.tram_id = dt1.tram_id
where dt1.name = 'CitySquare' and dt2.name = '$name2' LIMIT 5");

Comment: This only shows me the columns name1, time1, name2, time2 and not the rest of them. It is fetching the data but I want both queries to be in separate columns @Abelisto

Comment: `UNION` joins queries vertically. To join horizontally use `JOIN` instead.

Comment: I want them to join vertically which it is doing perfectly fine from the first subquery, but it does not show the columns for the second subquery. That's the problem I am having @Abelisto

Comment: Don't edit your question in such a way that it becomes useless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, you want to create an output that lists the 5 trams going from some station to City Square and 5 trams going from City Square to some other station. In this case - you are not making any connection (for instance, on time) between these two things - you should join on a pseudo-column, `row_number() OVER ()` comes to mind:

```
SELECT '$name' AS name1, w1.time1, 'City Square - arrival' AS name2, w1.time2,
       'City Square - departure' AS name3, w2.time3, '$name2' AS name4, w2.time4
FROM (
  SELECT dt1.time AS time1, dt2.time AS time2, row_number() OVER () AS rn
  FROM departure_times AS dt1
  JOIN departure_times AS dt2 USING (tram_id)
  WHERE dt1.name = '$name' AND dt2.name = 'CitySquare'
  LIMIT 5) w1
JOIN (
  SELECT dt1.time AS time3, dt2.time AS time4, row_number() OVER () AS rn
  FROM departure_times AS dt1
  JOIN departure_times AS dt2 USING (tram_id)
  WHERE dt1.name = 'CitySquare' AND dt2.name = '$name2'
  LIMIT 5) w2 USING (rn);
```

In each of the sub-queries you select the five rows of interest. Since there is no apparent property you can `JOIN` these two sets of rows on, you have to create some pseudo-column that can serve that purpose (you need something to join on or you will get a `CROSS JOIN` resulting in 5 x 5 rows in the output). Using [`row_number() OVER () AS rn`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) does just that: it creates a new column with alias `rn` which contains the row number over the entire row set (`OVER ()`, 5 rows because of the `LIMIT` clause). You do this in both sub-queries so you can use it as the join condition: `USING (rn)`. You do not have to use this column in the output.

You have no control over which 5 tram times will be listed. If you want that, you should do something like `WHERE dt1 > CURRENT_TIME` and `ORDER BY dt1` in both sub-queries, or something along that line.

Comment: Could you explain to me the solution which you have provided so I can understand what is going on, just to make things clear

Comment: @A.Khan You keep trying to delete significant parts of my answer. You can't do that. Once posted stuff hangs around at SO until a moderator or a reviewer decides otherwise. No one will allow you to delete such content so you might as well give up trying.

Answer (score 0):

Abelisto already gave you the first part, put parenthesis around the select queries.

For the second part of your question, if you want all the columns showing up, then you need to have all the columns in both queries. So something along the lines of adding `null::text AS name3, null::timestamp AS time3` etc. (Note that I'm guessing at your types with the type casting, you may have to change that according to the types that your query returns.

Comment: Both queries return a character varying type for the names and time without timezone type for the times. So I will need to add null::text AS name3, null::timestamp AS, time3 null::text AS name4, null::timestamp AS time4 in order for all the columns to show up.